# How would I replicate this GridView style using CSS?

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

Bit of a basic question, but I'm a bit rusty with CSS, but I've been requested to use CSS rather than the 'gridview style' tags (as I'll show below).

Basically, I use the following style on my GridView:

```
 <RowStyle BackColor="#ededed" ForeColor="#333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 <FooterStyle BackColor="#465F7F" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <PagerStyle BackColor="#465F7F" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#465F7F" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#465F7F" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 <EditRowStyle BackColor="#B7B7B7" />
 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#e2e6e8" ForeColor="#333333" />
```

Could I convert this to CSS? So I can just set my GridView CssClass and it'd apply all these styles. Right now that code is replicated on every grid, so changing it is a chore!

Comment: Please post the generated html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `CssClass` property of the grid and put everything to that css class and you're done!

For example instead of this:

```
<RowStyle BackColor="#ededed" ForeColor="#333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

you would use same markup for all your common style grids:

```
<RowStyle CssClass="gridViewRow" />
```

And the css class then would look like this:

```
.gridViewRow
{
   background-color:#ededed;
   color:#333;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By replacing the corresponding styles below you will get the same effect.

Also you should consider using JQuery Theme Roller's styles instead to easily make the grid look really nice. http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

```
.RowStyle
    {
          background-color: #ededed;
          color:#333;
          text-align:center;
    }
    .FooterStyle
    { 
        background-color:#465F7F; font-weight: bold; color:White;
    }
    .PagerStyle {background-color:#465F7F; color:White; text-align:center; }
    .SelectedRowStyle { background-color:#465F7F; font-weight: normal; color:#ffffff }
    .HeaderStyle {background-color:#465F7F; font-weight: normal; color:White; text-align:center; }
    .EditRowStyle {background-color:#B7B7B7; }
    .AlternatingRowStyle {background-color:#e2e6e8; color:#333333 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply your base style to the GridView and use the power of CSS

```
  <asp:GridView id="gvTestGrid" runat="server" cssclass="gridview-common" >
     <HeaderStyle cssClass="gridview-header" />
     ...
    </asp:GridView>
```

CSS

```
.gridview-common {  
  /* table styles */ 
 }

.gridview-common th.gridview-header, .gridview-common th.gridview-header:hover   {  
 /* Header styles */ 
 }

.gridview-common tbody tr {
     /* Row styles */ 
}

.gridview-common tbody tr:hover {
     /* Row Hover styles */ 
}
```